# 'setHasOptionsMenu(Boolean): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, fragment, android-inflate

How do I declare a menu inside of Android fragment? The method that I had used previously is now deprecated.

**Originally:**

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(...): View {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
```

```kotlin
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        this.menu = menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, this.menu)
    }
```

Comment: Did you read [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.5.0-alpha04) which linked to the [code snippets](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01)?

Comment: Why exactly was it deprecated? I don't see anything special about the new code...

Comment: "The Fragment APIs for providing a menu to your activity’s ActionBar have been deprecated as they tightly couple your fragment to your activity and are not testable in isolation. ", from the release notes mentioned above.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From the Developer documentation, this can be achieved by the following:

```
/**
  * Using the addMenuProvider() API directly in your Activity
  **/
class ExampleActivity : ComponentActivity(R.layout.activity_example) {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Add menu items without overriding methods in the Activity
   addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    })
  }
}

/**
  * Using the addMenuProvider() API in a Fragment
  **/
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
  
    // Add menu items without using the Fragment Menu APIs
    // Note how we can tie the MenuProvider to the viewLifecycleOwner
    // and an optional Lifecycle.State (here, RESUMED) to indicate when
    // the menu should be visible
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_clear -> {
                    // clearCompletedTasks()
                    true
                }
                R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                    // loadTasks(true)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
      }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
  }
```

[Fragments setHasOptionsMenu deprecated, use setHasOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01)

Comment: What about other functions, such as invalidation and getting a reference to the menu items? Those still exist, or also changed?

Comment: in fragment I would need to keep reference to the MenuProvider object so I can remove it by using removeMenuProvider(MenuProvider obj) cause of duplicated menus across multiple fragments ....you known how to do? Just tried it out but still have the issue

Comment: @riccardogabellone I got a similar issue, but I've noticed you can just pass the LifecycleOwner parameter to the addMenuProvider function, meaning in the fragment I use this: `activity!!.addMenuProvider(menuProviderThatYouCreated, this.viewLifecycleOwner)`

Comment: What does following mean?: // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation

Comment: `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` in fragment I see it's Required: MenuHost but Found: FragmentActivity

Comment: But how can we handle the back arrow press?

Comment: This looks weird. you have to inflate the xml twice? In activity and fragment? Or it can be in fragment only?

Answer (score 40):

Expanding on what @joseph-wambura and @hammad-zafar-bawara said, you can also implement the interface in the fragment...

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), MenuProvider {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Do stuff...
        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu)
        // Do stuff...
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Do stuff...
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` in fragment I see it's Required: MenuHost but Found: FragmentActivity How can use it?

Comment: Make sure that you are using `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and not the depreciated `import android.app.Fragment`

Comment: I already use this

Comment: This is a forced ComponentActivity (and by extension its fragments) change. There are devs still using CompatActivity without the forced component framework and the guides do not explain how to accomplish this for that scenario. requireActivity() in that case throws a type mismatch.

Comment: The solution for this is cast it, like so `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity() as MenuHost`

Comment: What is viewLifecycleOwner? Can I just use menuHost.addMenuProvider(this);?

Comment: You could do that @len, but (from my reading of the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01)) you would then be responsible for calling `menuHost.removeMenuProvider(this)` when the fragment is destroyed.

Comment: MenuProvider was added to the class implementation. That is why he can use requireActivity() directly.

Answer (score 29):

In Kotlin, declaration for `Activity`, `Fragment` and `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

#### Activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### Fragment

```kotlin
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()

    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.action_menu1 -> {
                    // todo menu1
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_menu2 -> {
                    // todo menu2
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
      }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
 }
```

#### PreferenceFragmentCompat

```kotlin
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireHost() as MenuHost
//Same declaration with Fragment
```

#### Use MenuProvider interface

```kotlin
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), MenuProvider {
 
      override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
              val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
              menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
      }
 
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu)
      }
 
      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_clear -> {
                    // Do stuff...
                    true
                }
                R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                    // Do stuff...
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
      }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```

Comment: Based from my tweet and personal blog notes, https://twitter.com/Codelaby/status/1558745982803869705?s=20&t=6ap1lh7Du3XjLP2DcEkxSQ

Comment: I tried but `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` giving error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity but MenuHost was expected`

Comment: After adding `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'` error disappeared  thanx

Comment: Please can you tell me what are the purpose of these two`` viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED``

Comment: With this parameter, you can tell the menu at what point in the fragment's life cycle it should be visible (in this case, the resume state).

Answer (score 16):

**JAVA CODE**

Option menu in **Activity**

```
addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, menu);

                // Add menu options here

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                // Handle Menu Options Selection Here

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Option menu in **Fragment**

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, menu);
                
                // Add option Menu Here
                
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
                
                // Handle option Menu Here
                
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```

Comment: in which method in fragment should use `requireActivity().addMenuProvider`?

Comment: I am using it in method "onCreateView".

Comment: I got `Unresolved reference: addMenuProvider` there's no method like this after requireActivity()

Comment: @Dr Mido try.        MenuHost menuHost = requireActivity();.        menuHost.addMenuProvider();

Comment: Thanks I tried but `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` giving error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity but MenuHost was expected`

Comment: After adding `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'` error disappeared thanx

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Jetpack NavigationUI then you need to `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, otherwise the menu will not be present.

Comment: Correct. If using navigation graph then this is must. Otherwise it MenuProvider will not work.

Answer (score 6):

this helps me on onCreateView Method:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, menu);
            
            // Add option Menu Here
            
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                           
            // Handle option Menu Here
             return false;
        }
    }, getViewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```

Comment: What if the menuprovider is in the main activity and i only want to add some code when a menu item is clicked when the fragment is in view/focused? Do i also have to inflate in onCreateMenu?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why all answers recommend passing in `Lifecycle.State.RESUME` as the lifecycle state to the `addMenuProvider` call. This will make the menu disappear when the fragment is paused, which doesn't look great when the fragment is paused and still visible.

For example, showing a dialog as a result of tapping a menu item will make the menu disappear. It will re-appear when the dialog is dismissed.

For most cases, a better lifecycle state to pass in would be `Lifecycle.State.CREATE`, which will only remove the menu when the view is destroyed. This is also the default behaviour, so you can simply omit the lifecycle state.

Answer (score 3):

For people who have flashbacks from Java, here is a bit better way using this extension function:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.addMenuProvider(@MenuRes menuRes: Int, callback: (id: Int) -> Boolean) {
    val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(menuRes, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem) = callback(menuItem.itemId)

    }
    (requireActivity() as MenuHost).addMenuProvider(
        menuProvider,
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
    )
}
```

and the usage:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    addMenuProvider(R.menu.feed_fragment) {
        when (it) {
            R.id.menu_write_post -> viewModel.goToPostCreation()
            R.id.menu_filter -> viewModel.goToFilter()
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

In case there is a need for feature flag, then you can repeat `addMenuProvider` call multiple times

Comment: this is actually really cool, because the callback is automatically removed when reaching onPause

Answer (score 2):

in java for fragment i tried this . it works fine for me

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_example, container, false);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    MenuHost menuHost = requireActivity();
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.search_friend){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    },getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);


    return view;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, I prefer creating an extension function to reduce boilerplate code:

Extension function implementation:

```
fun Fragment.setupMenu(@MenuRes menuId: Int, onMenuSelected: (MenuItem) -> Boolean) =
(requireActivity() as MenuHost).addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) =
        menuInflater.inflate(menuId, menu)

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem) = onMenuSelected(menuItem)
}, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

This way, you will always insure you are adding the `lifeCycleOwner` and passing the correct `lifecycle state` which is `Lifecycle.State.RESUMED`

And you can simply use this inside fragment calling:

```
setupMenu(R.menu.menu_save) { menuItem ->
    when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.save -> {
            viewModel.onSaveClicked()
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```