# Add frame dependent appbar Options menu In bottom navigation view layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I need to add a options menu for each fragment in bottom navigation view. currently each app bar has only the name of the fragment. I want to add specific options menu for each.

Comment: You no need to create appbar for every fragments... Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/how-to-add-options-menu-to-fragment-in-android#:~:text=Add%20setHasOptionsMenu(true)%20in%20the,items%20in%20your%20Fragment%20class.&text=You%20don't%20need%20to,onPrepareOptionsMenu%20method%20available%20in%20Fragment.&text=Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,-In%20my%20case

Comment: @GobuCSG the code there seems to be deprecated. Is there a latest version.

Comment: It's not deprecated... Share those code here...

Comment: Yes it is .. Now you need to use menuProvider in each fragment .

Comment: @GobuCSG I have answered the question myself.. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution
[here]: ['setHasOptionsMenu(Boolean): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917856/sethasoptionsmenuboolean-unit-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

one thing I would like to add is  so that the menu is removed when going to another fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
    requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(menuProvider);
}
```