# How to search active fragment recycle adapter list in android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

There are three fragments i.e., faculty, students, mentees. I want to search active fragment recycle adapter items.

[image]

Using search view as you see in the picture.

Here I am furnishing the code:

I am not able to implement

```
 private fun filter(msg: String) { 
}
```

in MainActivity.kt because as you know that fragments are not active and got the same error message after trying to implement it.

MainActivity.kt

```
package edu.cvr.csecontacts

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.faculty.Faculty
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.faculty.FacultyRecycleAdaptor
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.mentees.MenteeData
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.mentees.MenteeRecycleAdapter
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.mentees.Mentees
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.students.StudentData
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.students.StudentRecycleAdaptor
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.students.Students
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var bottomNav: BottomNavigationView

private lateinit var facultyAdapter: FacultyRecycleAdaptor
private lateinit var menteeAdapter: MenteeRecycleAdapter
private lateinit var studentAdapter: StudentRecycleAdaptor
//    val staff = InputStreamReader(assets.open("staff_contacts.csv"))



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val db = DBHelper(this, null)
    val cursor = db.getName()


    val faculty  = Faculty()
    val students = Students()
    val mentees = Mentees()
    loadFragment(Faculty())

    db.deleteFaculty()
    db.deleteMentees()
    db.deleteStudents()
    var tempArrayList: ArrayList<MenteeData>
    val student = InputStreamReader(assets.open("mentees.csv"))
    val reader = BufferedReader(student)
    var line : String?
    tempArrayList = arrayListOf()
    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null){
        val row : List<String> = line!!.split(",")
        //tempArrayList!!.add(FacultyData(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10]))
        db.addStudents(row[0],row[1],row[2])
        db.addMentees(row[0],row[1],row[2])
    }

    val facultyData = InputStreamReader(assets.open("staff_contacts.csv"))
    val reader1 = BufferedReader(facultyData)
    var line1 : String?
   // tempArrayList = arrayListOf()
    while (reader1.readLine().also { line1 = it } != null){
        val row : List<String> = line1!!.split(",")
        //tempArrayList!!.add(FacultyData(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10]))
        db.addName(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10])
    }

    //Faculty.newInstance(tempArrayList)

    var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNav)
    bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.faculty ->loadFragment(Faculty())
            R.id.students->loadFragment(students)
            else -> {loadFragment(mentees)}
        }
        true

    }





 }



private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        commit()
    }


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

    val inflater: MenuInflater = getMenuInflater()
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu)

    val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.search_action)
    val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            if (newText != null) {
                filter(newText)
            }
            return true
        }
    })

    return true
}



private fun filter(msg: String) {

  }

}
```

Faculty.kt

```
package edu.cvr.csecontacts.faculty

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.DBHelper
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.R


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [Faculty.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class Faculty : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var facultyAdapter: FacultyRecycleAdaptor




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_faculty, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        attachAdapter(view)
    }

    private fun attachAdapter(view: View) {
        val db = DBHelper(view.context,null)
        val rv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.faculty_fragment)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
        val data = db.listUser()
        rv.adapter = FacultyRecycleAdaptor(data)
    }



    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Faculty.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Faculty().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

FacultyRecycleAdaptor.kt

```
    package edu.cvr.csecontacts.faculty

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.FacultyData
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.R

class FacultyRecycleAdaptor(var tempArrayList: ArrayList<FacultyData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FacultyRecycleAdaptor.ViewHolder>() {
class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    lateinit var name:TextView
    lateinit var designation:TextView
    lateinit var call: ImageButton
    lateinit var msg: ImageButton
    lateinit var whatsapp: ImageButton

    init {
        name =itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        designation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subname)
        call = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call)
        msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg)
        whatsapp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whatsapp)
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int,
): ViewHolder {
    val v =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.name.setText(tempArrayList[position].name)
    holder.designation.setText(tempArrayList[position].designation)
    val context = holder.name.context
    holder.call.setOnClickListener(){
        val number = tempArrayList[position].college_mail_id.trim()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(number)))
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }

    holder.msg.setOnClickListener() {
        val number = tempArrayList[position].college_mail_id.trim()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:" + Uri.encode(number)))
        context.startActivity(intent)
        // startActivity(intent)
    }
    holder.whatsapp.setOnClickListener() {
        val number = tempArrayList[position].college_mail_id.trim()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:" + Uri.encode(number)))
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        context.startActivity(intent)
        // startActivity(intent)


    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return this.tempArrayList.size
}

fun filterList(facultyFilteredList: ArrayList<FacultyData>) {
    tempArrayList = facultyFilteredList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

DBHelper.kt

```
  package edu.cvr.csecontacts

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.SQLException
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.mentees.MenteeData
import edu.cvr.csecontacts.students.StudentData

class DBHelper(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

// below is the method for creating a database by a sqlite query
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    // below is a sqlite query, where column names
    // along with their data types is given
    val query = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_1 + " ("
           + ID_COL+" TXT," +
            NAME_COL + " TEXT," +
            GENDER_COL + " TEXT," +
            DESIGNATION_COL + " TEXT," +
            CONTACT_COL + " TEXT," +
            CVRMAIL_COL + " TEXT," +
            MAIL_COL + " TEXT," +
            DOJ_COL + " TEXT," +
            DOB_COL + " TEXT," +
            AADHAR_COL + " TEXT," +
            PAN_COL + " TEXT" + ")")

    val query2 = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_2 + " ("
            + ROLL_COL+" TXT," +
            NAME_COL + " TEXT," +
            CONTACT_COL + " TEXT" + ")")

    val query3 = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_3 + " ("
            + ROLL_COL+" TXT," +
            NAME_COL + " TEXT," +
            CONTACT_COL + " TEXT" + ")")

    // we are calling sqlite
    // method for executing our query

    try {
        db.execSQL(query2)
    }catch (e: SQLException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    db.execSQL(query)
    db.execSQL(query3)
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    // this method is to check if table already exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_1)
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_2)
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_3)
    onCreate(db)
}

// This method is for adding data in our database
fun addName(id: String,name : String,gender: String, designation : String, contact: String, cvrmail:String, personal_mail:String,doj: String, dob:String, aadhar:String, pan:String  ){

    // below we are creating
    // a content values variable
    val values = ContentValues()

    // we are inserting our values
    // in the form of key-value pair
    values.put(ID_COL,id)
    values.put(NAME_COL, name)
    values.put(GENDER_COL,gender)
    values.put(DESIGNATION_COL, designation)
    values.put(CONTACT_COL, contact)
    values.put(CVRMAIL_COL, cvrmail)
    values.put(MAIL_COL,personal_mail)
    values.put(DOJ_COL,doj)
    values.put(DOB_COL,dob)
    values.put(AADHAR_COL,aadhar)
    values.put(PAN_COL,pan)

    // here we are creating a
    // writable variable of
    // our database as we want to
    // insert value in our database
    val db = this.writableDatabase

    // all values are inserted into database
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME_1, null, values)

    // at last we are
    // closing our database
    //db.close()
}

// below method is to get
// all data from our database
fun getName(): Cursor? {

    // here we are creating a readable
    // variable of our database
    // as we want to read value from it
    val db = this.readableDatabase

    // below code returns a cursor to
    // read data from the database
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_1, null)

}

fun listUser(): ArrayList<FacultyData> {
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val storeUserInfo = ArrayList<FacultyData>()
    val curs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_1,null)
    if (curs!!.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            val id = curs!!.getString(0)
            val name = curs!!.getString(1)
            val gender = curs!!.getString(2)
            val designation = curs!!.getString(3)
            val mobN = curs!!.getString(3)
            val cvr_mail = curs!!.getString(4)
            val email = curs!!.getString(5)
            val doj = curs!!.getString(6)
            val dob = curs!!.getString(7)
            val aadhar = curs!!.getString(7)
            val pan = curs!!.getString(8)
            storeUserInfo.add(FacultyData(id,name,gender,designation,mobN,cvr_mail,email,doj,dob,aadhar,pan))
        } while (curs!!.moveToNext())
    }
    curs!!.requery()
   // curs!!.close()
    return  storeUserInfo
}

fun deleteFaculty(){
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    db.execSQL("DELETE from "+ TABLE_NAME_1)
}

fun deleteStudents(){
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    db.execSQL("DELETE from "+ TABLE_NAME_3)
}
fun deleteMentees(){
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    db.execSQL("DELETE from "+ TABLE_NAME_2)
}


fun addMentees(rollNo:String,name:String,mobile:String){
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(ROLL_COL,rollNo)
    values.put(NAME_COL,name)
    values.put(CONTACT_COL, mobile)

    val db = this.writableDatabase

    // all values are inserted into database
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME_2, null, values)

}
fun listMentees():ArrayList<MenteeData>{
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val storeMenteeInfo = ArrayList<MenteeData>()
    val curs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_2,null)
    if (curs!!.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val rollNo = curs!!.getString(0)
            val name = curs!!.getString(1)
            val mobile = curs!!.getString(2)

            storeMenteeInfo.add(MenteeData(rollNo, name, mobile))
        } while (curs!!.moveToNext())
    }
    curs!!.requery()
    //curs!!.close()
    return storeMenteeInfo
}

fun addStudents(rollNo:String,name:String,mobile:String){
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(ROLL_COL,rollNo)
    values.put(NAME_COL,name)
    values.put(CONTACT_COL, mobile)

    val db = this.writableDatabase

    // all values are inserted into database
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME_3, null, values)
}

fun listStudents():ArrayList<StudentData>{
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val storeStudentInfo = ArrayList<StudentData>()
    val curs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_3,null)
    if (curs!!.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val rollNo = curs!!.getString(0)
            val name = curs!!.getString(1)
            val mobile = curs!!.getString(2)

            storeStudentInfo.add(StudentData(rollNo, name, mobile))
        } while (curs!!.moveToNext())
    }
    curs!!.requery()
    //curs!!.close()
    return storeStudentInfo
}


companion object{
    // here we have defined variables for our database

    // below is variable for database name
    private val DATABASE_NAME = "cse"

    // below is the variable for database version
    private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1

    // below is the variable for table name
    val TABLE_NAME_1 = "faculty"

    val TABLE_NAME_2 = "mentees"

    val TABLE_NAME_3 = "students"

    // below is the variable for id column
    val ID_COL = "id"


    val ROLL_COL = "roll_no"

    // below is the variable for name column
    val NAME_COL = "name"

    val GENDER_COL = "gender"

    val DESIGNATION_COL = "designation"

    val CONTACT_COL = "contact"

    val CVRMAIL_COL = "cvrmail_id"

    val MAIL_COL = "personnel_mail"

    val DOJ_COL = "doj"

    val DOB_COL = "dob"

    val AADHAR_COL = "aadhar"

    val PAN_COL = "pan"

}
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding menu in the Activity, inflate the menu from each Fragment using `activity?.addMenuProvider` & handling the callback there.

Comment: I am sorry for being stupid. can you elaborate it

Comment: or you can give me any reference link to documentation or explanation that I can refer

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917856/sethasoptionsmenuboolean-unit-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java

Comment: Thanks I tried but `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` giving error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity but MenuHost was expected`

Comment: Hi after adding `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'` error disappeared. Thanx