How to add button to fragment toolbar?
I want to add a button here:

This menu is declared here:
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name=".ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
</navigation>

And used like that:
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

It's mostly the default example that is given by google.
I tried to add content to the <fragment> tag but it doesn't seems to be showed. Some video that I found are too old, and doesn't even talk about fragment.
My problem is because the view that contains the text isn't totally managed by me.
How can I add button on this fragment's toolbar?

What you provided is not a menu layout, but a navigation graph. These are not related things. You need to ceate a my_menu_name.xml file with <menu> and <item> elements. Then, inside Fragment class, you have to implement a MenuProvider like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965674/1860868

I know it's not a menu layout, it's just the top bar menu. Ok but how can I use this <menu> ? Like how to use with the navigation ?
